# How to add padding to a [sub]section in linker script to fill a specific size

Tags: c, linker, embedded, stm32

I have a stm32f4 mcu with 512 KB of flash memeory. The flash memory is divided in different sections as below:

[image: Flash memory of stm32f4 mcu]

I've dedicated the first 16KB section to bootloader. The bootloader executable is compiled separately and I insert padding bytes to it via `objcopy`:

```
COMMAND ${CMAKE_OBJCOPY} -O binary --pad-to 0x08004000 --gap-fill 0xff $<TARGET_FILE:${BOOTLOADER}> ${BOOTLOADER}.bin)
```

and load it before main application using the linker script.

I want to keep some tuning parameters in the second section so they would not change after a hard-reset.

Problem is I don't know how to padd the parameter section to fit exactly in 16KBs so when re-writing the values from application or bootloader (flash sections should be wiped before writing), other sections of the code do not get corrupted.

This is the linker script's text section:

```
SECTIONS
{
    .text : {
        KEEP(*(.bootloader_section)) /* 16 KB */
        KEEP(*(.parameters_section)) /* 16 KB HOW??? */ 
        
        /* Main application: should start from 0x8008000 = 32KB offset from flash base */
        *(.vectors) /* Vector table */
        KEEP(*(.firmware_info))
        *(.text*)   /* Program code */
        . = ALIGN(4);
        *(.rodata*) /* Read-only data */
        . = ALIGN(4);
    } >rom
```

And also there is a `parameters.c` file in the project which contains parameter values:

```
__attribute__((section(".parameters_section"))) Parameters_t param = {
    .tuning.value1 = 0x4,
    .tuning.value2 = 0x3,
    .tuning.value3 = 0x2,
    .tuning.value4 = 0x3,
    .reserved4 = 0xaaaaaaaa,
    .reserved5 = 0xaaaaaaaa,
    .reserved6 = 0xaaaaaaaa,
    .reserved7 = 0xaaaaaaaa,
    .reserved8 = 0xaaaaaaaa,
    .reserved9 = 0xaaaaaaaa,
    .reserved10 = 0xaaaaaaab,
    .reserved11 = 0xaa0aaaaa,
    .reserved12 = 0xaaaaaaaa,
    .reserved13 = 0xaaaaaaaa,
    .reserved14 = 0xaaaaaaaa,
    .reserved15 = 0xaaaaaaaa,
    .reserved16 = 0xaaaaaaaa,
    .reserved17 = 0xaaaaaaaa,
    .reserved18 = 0xaaaaaaaa,
    .reserved19 = 0xaaaaaaaa,
};
```

Should I also compile the `parameters.c` separate from other source files and pad it using `objcopy`? or is there other ways to do this?

Comment: Your linker script has for sure some `memory` specification. Can't you use that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just define memory sections for the various things you want, and make sure the relevant things go in each?

This is completely untested, but hopefully shows the intent.

```
MEMORY
{
  RAM         (xrw) : ORIGIN = 0x20000000,  LENGTH = 36K
  BOOTFLASH   (rx)  : ORIGIN = 0x8000000,   LENGTH = 16K
  PARAMETERS  (r)   : ORIGIN = 0x8004000,   LENGTH = 16K
  APPFLASH    (rx)  : ORIGIN = 0x8008000,   LENGTH = 128K
}

SECTIONS
{
    .boottext : {
        KEEP(*(.bootloader_section)) /* 16 KB */
    } > BOOTFLASH

    .parameters : {
        KEEP(*(.parameters_section)) /* 16 KB */
    } > PARAMETERS

    .text : {
        *(.vectors) /* Vector table */
        KEEP(*(.firmware_info))
        *(.text*)   /* Program code */
        . = ALIGN(4);
        *(.rodata*) /* Read-only data */
        . = ALIGN(4);
    } > APPFLASH
...
}
```

You'd need to correct the size of the RAM and the APPFLASH, I just used random numbers there, since I don't know about how much RAM you have, and couldn't be bothered calculating the remaining flash size.

Comment: This works. But a small issue: The bootloader binary does not get loaded into the main application firmware (I add it using assembly command `incbin "path/to/bootloader.bin"` in my application source code). Which is fine because it should be removed in the production firmware anyway. 

I guess for assembly `incbin` to work, the `.bootloader_section` should be added as a subsection to `.text`

Comment: It depends on how you want to build it. If you're building the application completely separately, just remove the BOOTFLASH memory area (and references to it in the SECTIONS). Then you can end up with a .bin that needs to be loaded at `0x08008000`. Some people want to build a combined image that contains the bootloader and the application though. There are choices to be made.

Comment: In the development and debugging process the second approach is more convenient. Although your solution is best of both worlds. Using make targets, I have a choice to flash each image separately or flash both of them together with one command.